# IIS 8 asp.net mvc HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, asp.net-mvc

Hello i have just moved server, for my asp.net mvc framework. but now i get the following error message, and to be honest i do now know what is wrong?

> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    BeginRequest
>
> Handler    Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x80070021
>
> Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this
>   path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
>   Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
>   explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
>   allowOverride="false".

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CosplayConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=sogaard.us;Initial Catalog=NewCosplay;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MaxImageSize" value="5242880" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RecaptchaPrivateKey" value="6LeAsuASAAAAAKigNk4qtA5iS_E0RPmYTcQM9U4Z" />
    <add key="RecaptchaPublicKey" value="6LeAsuASAAAAAO8HMUg9HKihCMRx0s53Dazbpoag" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Recaptcha" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="CosplayRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CosplayRoleProvider" type="Sogaard.us.Cosplay.Library.CosplayRoleProvider, Sogaard.us.Cosplay, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationname="Cosplay" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules></httpModules>
    <httpHandlers></httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RouteMagic" publicKeyToken="84b59be021aa4cee" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.2.2.2" newVersion="0.2.2.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We had the same error on a brand new server.

The reason was not the default IIS security policy, stored in `applicationHost.config`, as suggested by [the other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/514095/118258) (although we checked that). The reason was that we installed IIS without support for ASP.NET (an ASP.NET 4.5 role)!

When we installed the missing support for ASP.NET, our application just started with no changes in configuration at all.

Conclusion:

**Double check that you have ASP.NET role installed along with IIS if you get this error.**

---

To install the ASP.NET role in Windows Server:

1. Open the add roles and features wizard
2. Check the ASP.NET [your_version] entry under `Web Server (IIS)` -> `Web Server` -> `Application Development`

To install the ASP.NET role in a Windows client:

1. Open Turn Windows features on or off wizard
2. Check the ASP.NET [your_version] entry under `Internet Information Services` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features`

Comment: Thanks, glad I found this. After installing the Role services, I had to turn on ASP.NET v4.0.30319 in the ISAPI and CGI restrictions feature.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it tells you what is wrong. The `system.webServer/Handlers` section has been locked somewhere else, meaning that you can not override it in the `web.config` file at the current level (probably the web site).

Either remove:

```
<handlers>
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

from your `web.config` file

Or find out where it has been locked and change it.
It is probably locked in the `applicationHost.config` file. It can be found here: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\`. Open it with a text editor and look for a line like

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

Change the `overrideModeDefault` attribute to Allow

---

Alternatively, you can use [`appcmd.exe`](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) to unlock the section for a specific site or application, like this:

```
appcmd.exe unlock config "WebSiteName/app" -section:system.webServer/Handlers
```

Where "WebSiteName" is the name of the web site and "/app" is the path to your application. To unlock it for the entire web site:

```
appcmd.exe unlock config "WebSiteName" -section:system.webServer/Handlers
```

Comment: I get teh same heeor when i use the appcmd.exe C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe unlock config "test.cosplay.dk/app" -sect
ion:system.webServer/Handlers
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: \\?\C:\Server\Kasper\Web\test.cosplay.dk\web.config
Line Number: 71
Description: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happen
s when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (ov
errideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode
="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
. )

Comment: But this is a completly new installed server, and this is the first website that is deplyed on it, how can something else lock the handelers?

Comment: Then remove the `Handlers` section. It could be locked by default. Did you migrate the site from a Win2008 box?

Comment: Yes Win2008R2, if i remove the handelers and modules will mvc not work! i got the it accept the handlers with the command, but modules will not follow :(